# Splitting tags with a PHP Include

Tags: php, php-include

So I'm setting up a portfolio and print selling website, and a lot of the text on the individual product pages is going to be generic. To avoid typing and make updates easier I'm thinking about heavily using php includes. I'm wondering if it's safe to split a paragraph (or other) tag into a PHP include, like this:

```
<p>This image, [title], photographed at the Biltmore Gardens in late Summer 2015, <?php include '../include/generictext.php';?>
```

And then generictext.php would have the closing paragraph tag:

```
is printed on Canson Infinity Platine Fibre Rag 310. This excellent fine art paper offers blah blah blah</p>
The following sizes are available:<br>
...
```

Is that safe?

Comment: Try a database, their great for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly safe. The only thing the PHP interpreter looks for in this context is `<?`; everything else gets passed through unchanged, so it doesn't matter that the `include()` happens in the middle of a paragraph.

It's even safe (albeit confusing) to put an opening PHP tag in the middle of an HTML tag, e.g.

```html
<div class="<?php include "blah" ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I've been using them like crazy contained with an attribute's string like that, but I was afraid splitting tags might be different. You've saved me some repetitive typing!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar set up before moving my site to a database, the URL would point to a php page containing only variables, then that page would include another containing the template for output, eg.

thisprint.php

```
<?php
$title = 'nice photo';
$location = 'some place';
$date = 'summer 2015';

include 'template.php';
?>
```

template.php

```
<p>This image, <?= $title ?>, photographed at <?= $location ?> in <?= $date ?>, is printed on Canson Infinity Platine Fibre Rag 310. This excellent fine art paper offers blah blah blah</p>
The following sizes are available:<br>
...
```

This works great for smaller sites, but as I found out becomes difficult to maintain/expand as the site gets bigger and bigger and this is where a database comes into its own.

Comment: Do you have any good how-to links on databases for this sort of simple purpose? This site is indeed too small for it but it's something I'm curious about.

On the PHP variables example, would that work if you used it over and over (many images)? Would the variables just redefine every time? I considered this method but was afraid you'd need unique variables for each image (sort of defeating the point). So I went with PHP includes and have a "name.php" and "location.php" file in every image folder - which is way more of a pain than a variables list.

Comment: I got up to around 500 pages using this method before it got too much. The variables will reset on each page load so you can use the same variable names for every page and one single file to contain your template. Google is your best starting point for starting out with databases, but one thing I will say is quite a few tutorial sites are now out of date so if you see any that are using functions that start with `mysql_` don't use them because they have been deprecated in favour of the more secure `mysqli_` (the 'i' meaning 'improved').